# Add and transform layers of images and text like Photoshop fx

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is just a question of approach and ideas, rather than solving an issue.

You know it from Photoshop, where you can add layers of text and images onto each other and transform and move them around to design a complete image.

What do you call this? And do you know some jQuery plugins that does this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I don't need any other Photoshop feature, as blending, filters etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**

You should have a look at jQuery-UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/).

Using those on *layers* (*distinct `<div>`, `<img>` or whatever tag elements*) you can simulate that..
Adding transparent-background `<textarea>` elements in the mix, and you can have text as well..

something like http://jsfiddle.net/MrzsG/

---

**original answer**

You can do that (*minus the layer blending effects*) with CSS positioning and opacity..

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gUYb3/1/

---

For the blending effects you would need to create the algorithms and use canvas drawing..

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't need any filtering. Just the layers and transform, but I need to transform it like I do in Photoshop. With anchors where I can scale the layer, and add layers with text and edit this.

Comment: It's not what I mean. I know jQuery UI, and I know a lot of jQuery in general. I just need the name for the features or a link to a plugin which already do this.